# Netflix cartoon series where the main character had a leather gaunlet that could summon a beast

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

So, my brother watched a cartoon series a couple of years ago and now can't seem to remember what the name of the cartoon series was.

All he does remember is:

- It was on Netflix.
- Year around 2014 (it was a new release)

The main character had a leather gauntlet around his right hand which he could magically use to summon a beast from an alternate dimension.

The beast looks a bit like large monituor and it's name was Bob.

The kids parents also has the same abilities although his father has gone missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might you be looking for *[Kaijudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaijudo)*?

> Kaijudo is an American animated action/adventure TV series which is related to the Kaijudo collectible card game issued by Wizards of the Coast, a subsidiary of Hasbro since 1999. It is a re-imagining of the widely successful Duel Masters franchise. It is produced by Hasbro Studios, animated by Moi Animation in South Korea, and developed by Henry Gilroy and Andrew R. Robinson for Wizards of the Coast. The series, partly owned by Hasbro, aired on the Hub Network in the United States from June 2, 2012 to December 28, 2013. The show's first season is titled Kaijudo: Rise of the Duel Masters. The second season, premiered on June 21, 2013 on the Hub Network, is titled Kaijudo: Clash of the Duel Masters.

....

> The series follows the adventures of a young boy named Ray Okamoto from San Campion who possesses the rare ability to summon and duel alongside fantastical creatures from a parallel dimension. Ray and his two best friends Allie and Gabe join the ranks of the mysterious Duel Masters to ensure the survival of both races.

You can see Ray's glove, and his family with the same powers, in this clip:

They also do mention in the clip that his summon is named Bob.

Found with a search for *netflix cartoon summon gauntlet bob*

Comment: yes that was the cartoon, he was looking for. thanks